# Bind checkbox or multi-select dropdown to array in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angularjs, html-select, html.checkbox

I am new to AngularJS, and am thus confused as how to bind checkboxes or multi-select dropdowns to a separate list.

```html
<body ng-controller="FooListCtrl">
  <span ng-repeat="foolist in foos">
    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="foo for foo in foolist" multiple="">
    </select>
  </span>
</body>
```

```js
'use strict';

function FooListCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.foos = {"Bar": [ "foo", "bar"]};
    $scope.selected = [];
}

FooListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Run the code: http://jsfiddle.net/gBcN2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got right what you want:

1. You don't have `ng-app` definition.
2. On jsFiddle for snippets of AngularJS put `No wrap - in <head>` load mode, if you are using AngularJS as external resource.
3. Model `selected` has it's own "range", because you use `ng-repeat`. To see what I mean, here is fixed version of your code:
   http://jsfiddle.net/gBcN2/2/

First `{{selected}}` works fine, but second is "outside" of `ng-repeat` scope.

PS:
You don't have to use `ng-repeat` if you want to use it like you wrote in your example: [quick fiddle of how I'd do it.](http://jsfiddle.net/qQg8u/1/)

**Edit:**
For checkboxes it's something like that - http://jsfiddle.net/qQg8u/2/

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help. If possible would you also be able to show me what a checkbox example would look like? :)

Comment: Thanks, that is good; but is there one which doesn't edit the source JSON (with `checked: false` values)?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think there's got to be a "storage" place to somehow check if checkbox is checked or not (sorry for tautology :)). If you don't want to change JSON contents of that `optionSource` you can use other variables, like that: http://jsfiddle.net/qQg8u/5/ That way options source will be untouched.

Comment: FYI: Got one to work which gives me an array of checked boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/C7eRd/1

Comment: Nice! :) Surely there are a lot of options how to make the same thing visually.